# Как задержать код на с++

Tags: c++, g++

Как задержать программу на определенное количество миллисекунд , используя только библиотеки из bits/stdc++.h

Comment: просто добавлю, слипо-ориентированное программирование зло) почитайте про примитивы синхронизации ))))

Comment: Есть основания полагать, что это проблема XY. Зачем вам вдруг понадобилось "задерживать" программу? Случаем не для printf отладки какой-нибудь. `bits/stdc++.h` - это внутренний заголовочный файл, который использовать не следует.

Comment: @user7860670 да он даже не внутренний, просто какая то склянка для учебных целей максимум. Скорее всего ТС хотел указать просто stl

Answer (score 5):

Вот пример как сделать delay() :

**Stl варианты (STD C++):**

sleep_for - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Просто скажите текущему потоку подождать (кол-во определяется в chrono https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) )

```
#include<chrono>
#include<thread> 

int main(){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50000000));
}
```

Есть еще sleep_until - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until
который ждет наступления определенного времени

```
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>

int main(){
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(1000000));
}
```

**Системные варианты**

Sleep:

для WIn32

```
#include "windows.h"
....
Sleep(5000);
```

Для Gnu/Linux

Sleep - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html

Usleep - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html

```
#include <unistd.h>
....
sleep(5); 
usleep(5);
```

P.s. usleep вроде как не соответствует POSIX

Answer (score 0):

Если устроит GCC , то `sleep` был там давно.

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wpedantic nanosleep.cpp -o nanosleep
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <errno.h>
# if _POSIX_C_SOURCE < 199309L
# error _POSIX_C_SOURCE < 199309L
# endif
int main(){
  struct timespec req ;
  req . tv_sec = 3 ;
  req . tv_nsec = 500000000 ;
  struct timespec rem ;
  int e = nanosleep ( & req , & rem ) ;
  if ( e ) {
    fprintf ( stderr , "error = %s\n" , strerror(errno) ) ;
    fprintf ( stderr , "rem = { %ld + %ld / 1 000 000 000 }\n" ,
      rem . tv_sec , rem . tv_nsec ) ; } }
```

Comment: самый быстрый стрелок на западе ? зачем столько лишнего ???

Comment: `usleep(5000000)` в любом \*nix

Comment: @avp `usleep` вышел позже (2008-09). И не очень удобно, если нужны ещё с целыми секундами.

Comment: Мне помнится, он появился в bsd 4.3, которая попала к нам где-то в 1988 - 89-м

Comment: @avp usleep уже же не posix????

Comment: @avp я плохо перевёл. `usleep` убрали из POSIX 2008-09

Comment: @avp теперь все верно, вместо неё рекомендуется sleep и nanosleep

Comment: @Maggot, да, в manpage объявлена obsolete аж с 2001-го, но реально все еще работает и imho никуда не денется. Удобна ведь, и ничего тут не поделаете ... (на крайний случай реализуется за 5 минут в виде static inline)